# How to create a lightning component to be a container for other components in App Builder?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, app-builder

Is there a way to create a component as a container for other components as the standard "Tabs" component do ("Add component(s) here") ?

[image]

Comment: No sorry, this is currently not possible. Source: I'm a developer on the Lightning App Builder team at Salesforce (seems my answer to this question was deleted)

Comment: Here is a similar question http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/153578/lightning-components-are-container-components-usable-in-the-lightning-app-build

Comment: @Kristian i am looking for something similar, and if we have that, it could open amazing possibilities to offer layouts to customers, specially on App pages. Is this feature on road map ?

Comment: @AbhinavGupta check out the new custom page templates feature in Winter 18, maybe that covers some of your use cases? https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_forcecom_lab_custom_templates.htm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it is currently not possible. (I am a developer on the App Builder team at Salesforce.)

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! If you are part of the development team, that's a perfectly legitimate source for any claim you make, especially about that product! But if you don't include that information in your answer and it's not clear based on your profile, it's hard to assess the validity of your contribution. I've gone ahead and added it for you. With all that out of the way, we're always glad to have more participation from the team! Welcome aboard!

Comment: And is it in the road map?

Comment: It is definitely something we want to support, but I don't know when that will happen. What we do have today to allow you to customize the layout is custom page templates, which may be able to solve some of your use cases.  https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_forcecom_lab_custom_templates.htm

Comment: @Kristian has anything changed since the last comment here?

Comment: No sorry, no update on this. I'd encourage you to log it on ideaexchange to help our product team prioritize.