# How to create Lightning Components that are containers for other Lightning Components?

Tags: lightning, app-builder

I've seen some [similar](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/158187/how-to-create-a-lightning-component-to-be-a-container-for-other-components-in-ap) questions about this subject, but they are really old and I'm not sure if those answers still hold true today (6 years latter), so..

Is it currently possible to create a parent Lightning component that contains areas/slots where I can drag/drop child components inside using the App Builder?

The idea is similar to the Tabs standard component (parent/container) with any other component (as child).

Please notice I'm not referring to Lightning templates (as a page template), but rather the components themselves.

[image]

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: From my understanding, this still isn't supported. It would be great to understand the use case though, and how it is distinct from the Tabs component for example?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @CallumMacErlich . I'd like to create something similar to the "dynamic forms" recently introduced by salesforce, but with more options like more columns per line, column widths, other types of data representations (slider, radio, etc) and since the the AppBuilder already have the drag & drop mechanism that would be perfect for this case, since the user would not need to switch to another place only to configure the component.

Comment: That's definitely not supported at the moment. In terms of columns, there is [this](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdizwUAB/provide-a-standard-lightning-container-component-that-implements-columns) Idea that you should vote on but it doesn't have much traction to date. In terms of radios, sliders such, that sounds more like data entry than a view. If it is then your best bet would be to use a flow, which supports those as well as multiple columns.